# How to message between CPU Cores in Node?

Tags: node.js, hook.io

I have an application that I'm working on that needs to sync a timer between multiple cores (using cluster).

Is there an efficient reliable way that I can communicate between cores? I've looked at Redis, but that seems to be more geared towards client/server communication. I'd be grateful for any advice.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to take a look at [hook.io](https://github.com/hookio/hook.io):**

> hook.io creates a distributed node.js EventEmitter that works
>   **cross-process** / **cross-platform** / **cross-browser**. Think of it like a
>   real-time event bus that works anywhere JavaScript is supported.

Comment: All good answers. I'm going to go with hook.io since it's very well documented.

Comment: Too bad hook.io died... Anyone found a replacement?

Answer (score 2):

Look at message queue services such as ZeroMQ. They have advantage of supporting both local IPC and TCP transports, so you are ready for horizontal scalability beyond cores available on a single cloud node. zmq has a binding for node.

Comment: RabbitMQ is also awesome. Also pub/sub with redis, or just socket.io

Comment: Using ZeroMQ is a very bad idea, performance suck. This is due to the JS wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/substack/dnode
You can use it to communicate between nodejs processes.